# How to write Db in Wordpress?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have written a custom query to retrieve data in WordPress and it works fine in my local so when I move to the real environment its syntax will be like?

$dbconnect =  mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','goldenstatecanna');

$query = mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT *

FROM wp_terms JOIN wp_termmeta

WHERE wp_terms.term_id = wp_termmeta.term_id

and wp_termmeta.meta_key = \"display_type\"

and wp_termmeta.meta_value != \"subcategories\"");

Need to know how to write that with Wordpress Syntax

Comment: seems you are trying to fetch the data for wp_terms, why dont you try the `get_terms` or `WP_Term_Query` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wpdb Class, this global WordPress class is key for using queries. In fact, every function uses this class.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(apple) FROM fruits";
$wpdb->query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by this code

```
  global $wpdb;

    $querystr = "
    SELECT *
    FROM $wpdb->terms termss JOIN $wpdb->termmeta termssmeta
    WHERE termss.term_id = termssmeta.term_id 
    AND termssmeta.meta_key = 'display_type'
    AND termssmeta.meta_value != 'subcategories' ";

    $dataa = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);
    print_r($dataa);
```

You can also refer this https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query

Answer (score 0):

You should declare $wpdb as global before use it. It does work as an ORM for the Wordpress application, and there is a very extensive documentation about it, take a look, https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb